# Weird behavior of NSCollectionView after window resize

Tags: swift, macos, layout, resize, nscollectionview

Here is how I setup my collectionview:

```
    let layout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20
    pCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout

    pCollectionView.backgroundColors = [NSColor.clear]
    pCollectionView.dataSource = self
    pCollectionView.delegate = self
    pCollectionView.isSelectable = true
```

And in the collectionview's delegate:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSSize {
        return NSSize(width: 240, height: 135)
    }
```

At first, it looks good.
[image]

But after I resized the App's window, weired things come up.Here is how it looks like:

[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I found it is completely my fault.

In the collectionview's delegate method, I forgot to use `func makeItem(withIdentifier identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem`, instead I am using `init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` every time!.

I felt such a fool.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the size of the cells according to the size of the collectionView.frame

```
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20
```

Is not a constraint and will not keep the cells like you want them.

You will have to :

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
         //work out the size of cell according to how many you want in a row
         return CGSize(width: screenWidth/3, height: cellHeight)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just found out the problem, it is not about layout but the way to load `NSCollectionViewItem`.